# Tap on UIView and change color itself

Tags: uiview, swift3

I need to change color of UIView  then I tap on it. How I can do this?

P.S. Sorry for my english

Comment: so add a `gesture recognizer` to your view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here are the steps.

1. Drag a UIView to your ViewController
2. Then create an IBOutlet to it. (just drag a connection to your viewcontroller class).
3. then create gesture for it.
4. then create an action for it.
5. assign the action

here is the full code for your view controller

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    //Outlet Connection to your View

    @IBOutlet weak var myView: UIView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        myView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        myView.layer.borderWidth = 2


        let taptoColorGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer.init(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.changeMyColor))
        myView.addGestureRecognizer(taptoColorGesture)

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }


    func changeMyColor () {

        let colorR : Float = Float(Int(arc4random_uniform(255)))
        let colorG : Float = Float(arc4random_uniform(255))
        let colorB : Float = Float(arc4random_uniform(255))

        let themyColor = UIColor.init(colorLiteralRed: colorR/255, green: colorG/255, blue: colorB/255, alpha: 1.0)

        myView.backgroundColor = themyColor

       //this function creates random color each time
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

and here is the project url to github [Change the UIView Color on tap in Swift](https://github.com/AnuradhS/ChangeViewcolorOnTap)

Answer (score 0):

// first go to identity inspector and set 'user interaction enabled' on the view
// Then put this in the viewDidLoad method (change :myExampleView to your view name)

```
let tapChangeColor = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(changeColor)) 
self.myExampleView.addGestureRecognizer(tapChangeColor)
```

// put this method somewhere in ViewController class:

```
func changeColor() {

self.myExampleView.backgroundColor=UIColor.blue

}
```